# Does "The Great Reset" seek to abolish property rights?

Tags: economics

[The Great Reset](https://www.weforum.org/great-reset/) is a plan by the World Economic Forum, imagined by a gentleman named [Klaus Schwab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaus_Schwab).

The plan is somewhat controversial, with [some media outlets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pF_kXE-HXSQ&ab_channel=SkyNewsAustralia) portraying it as an agenda to abolish property rights as we know it.

I saw this tweet, allegedly by WEF, that says "you will own nothing":

[image: You will own nothing]

Is this plan aimed at abolishing property rights?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because - at the moment - it is a question about the alleged hidden *motivations* of a small group of people, and there is no way such a question can be answered. However, maybe the Insiders show you link to makes a specific testable claim. I watched for a while, and didn't hear any. Please find the specific claim being made and transcribe it (with a timestamp), so readers don't need to sit through 10 minutes of propaganda to hear it.

Comment: The explicit motivations are included on the [official site you linked to](https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2020/06/now-is-the-time-for-a-great-reset/).

Comment: And you'll rent everything from the guy who owns LIDL and most of Germany (by then), LOL. Since you've quoted their own official Twitter, I'm not seeing how this is worthy of a question here. Bad PR isn't usually on-topic.

Comment: @Fizz: The tweet seems unrelated to the project. I don't know if the OP linked the two or one of his sources.

Comment: @Oddthinking: the q should have probably quoted from the Sky guy who did link the "great reset" with the "own nothing" https://youtu.be/pF_kXE-HXSQ?t=270 from year prior. The usual drivel from Murdoch-owned media: the Sky dude also claims that the Covid measures were intended for this purpose of replacing shareholders with "left-wing bureaucrats" etc.

Comment: @Fizz: Leaving quality of the journalism and the political posturing, I agree that the question should quote an actual specific claim from David Speers.

Comment: @Oddthinking: I think you mean Rowan Dean (the Sky presenter, who did link the issues).

Comment: They actually provide quotes in the youtube summary: "Mr Dean said “if implemented successfully, The Great Reset will undeniably and deliberately have extreme and possibly dire repercussions”.

“‘You'll own nothing, and you'll be happy’ is just one of their marketing slogans,” he said. “The plan involves replacing shareholders of big companies with stakeholders, who happen to be left-wing bureaucrats and climate change zealots. Replacing Mum and Dad small businesses and private enterprises with big tech and big business”.

Comment: @Fizz: [face-palm] I have confused this show - Outsiders, hosted by Rowan Dean - with Insiders, hosted by David Speers. I am laughing at myself.

Comment: actual suggestions for "Great Reset" are laid out here, if anyone has kindle unlimited https://smile.amazon.com/COVID-19-Great-Reset-Klaus-Schwab-ebook/dp/B08CRZ9VZB/

Comment: It's ironic because the original article by Ida Auken was apparently meant to be dystopic and trigger reflection on ever-growing data sharing and surveillance, and had the usual disclaimers of representing only the views of its author. The piece was published at the time (2016) as part of ...

Comment: ... [a feature on the world of 2030](https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2016/11/8-predictions-for-the-world-in-2030/), which pointed out that it was not that rosy if you looked closely. But someone at the WEF had chosen to depict it in the first degree in the accompanying video on that page, with the unfortunate "And you'll be happy" slogan, so conspiracy theorists can now cherry-pick and claim there's a conspiracy to eliminate private property.

Comment: "Owning nothing and being happy" sounds a lot like end-stage capitalism where interest rates are zero, asset prices are infinity, and everything must be rented.

Comment: @user253751: We can speculate about what is meant by reading the title alone, but that isn't helpful, especially if the article isn't related.

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer, but regarding that specific post, the author clarifies:

https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2016/11/shopping-i-can-t-really-remember-what-that-is/

> Author's note: Some people have read this blog as my utopia or dream
> of the future. It is not. It is a scenario showing where we could be
> heading - for better and for worse. I wrote this piece to start a
> discussion about some of the pros and cons of the current
> technological development. When we are dealing with the future, it is
> not enough to work with reports. We should start discussions in many
> new ways. This is the intention with this piece.

Comment: if its not an answer, why?

Comment: @Topcode I don't know anything about the WEF or what their claims or goals are... someone can probably make a more comprehensive answer